# How do you prove that there does not exist a $3 \times 3$ matrix over $\Bbb{Q}$ such as $A^8=I$ and $A^4 \ne I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am kind of stuck with the following problem:

Prove that there does not exist a $3 \times 3$ matrix over $\Bbb{Q}$ such as $A^8=I$ and $A^4 \ne I$.

I already tried some things and got that if $A^8=I$, then $(A^4)^2=I$.

And I guess a similar reasoning would work for this one.   I bet that I am missing something obvious but I can't find what is it :(

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $(x^8 - 1) = (x^4-1)(x^4+1)$, and $(x^4+1)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: You should make that an answer.

Comment: The question mixes $A^8=I$ and later $A^8=0$, which is wrong. Please make sure this is made coherent; I suppose you meant $A^8=I$ throughout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: The minimal polynomial of A divides $(x^8−1)=(x^4−1)(x^4+1)$, and $(x^4+1)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: $8$ up votes for comment and only $3$ up votes for answer?? :O

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot